# Replace ajax response of a json file from a website to a local json file

Tags: ajax, apache, http, localhost, hosts

So basically I saw a website who does an ajax call to its backend and fetch a json file with some data. I want to manipulate that data by duplicating that file locally and edit it and somehow map it in hosts file in order the website to fetch my file instead of theirs just to be able to see some data on their website manipulated by me. Is this doable in any way ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to inject a custom JSON response to replace a request made to the server?  There's a Chrome extension called "tweak" which may be of use to you.